# How do I add a screenshot for my package?

Tags: debian, repository

I created a repository with `reprepro` and it is working fine, but I would like to add the "images" to the packages when they are displayed with some package manager such as synaptic.

At first, i was having problems with change-logs too, but when asking for a change-log the following message is displayed `URI was: http://foo/pool/main/7/7zrecover/7zrecover_2.6_all.changelog`

So I understood that I needed to create that URL in order to call the change-log. I did it and it worked. I wanted to use the same method to call the image of the package, but when the error is displayed the URL is not shown so I don't have any idea of what URL is being requested. I've also been doing Internet researches but I just get dumb stuff or packages!

Open synaptic and select any package. Then you will see that in the package description there are two buttons "Get Screenshoot" and "Get Changelog". I would like to make work the "Get Screenshoot" button of my packages.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of screenshots (they are so AU), but in this case, perhaps you can include one (of synaptic) to show what you want?

Comment: @Faheem There is no need :), To see an example of what i want to do just: Open synaptic and select any package. Then you will see that in the package description there are two buttons "Get Screenshoot" and "Get Changelog". I would like to make work the "Get Screenshoot" button. As a Debian user i don't really care but i know that in other package managers like the one used by Ubuntu, the package image is displayed automatically and i would like fill it

Comment: I have no idea what this question means. What do you mean by “image package URL” and “call the image of the package”? Is *image* the wrong translation for some word in your native language? If you're getting errors, then explain **precisely** what you're doing and **copy-paste** the full error messages.

Comment: I think OP's package manager has some way to display screenshots of packages, probably from http://screenshots.debian.net/

Comment: @Gilles, if i would have Somme error i would have post it. Package managers like synaptic of the one used by ubuntu can display an "image of the package" and they do it by downloading the image from an url. i want to know the url. As you can read from my post i discovered the url of the changelogs but not the one of the pictures.

Comment: @derobert Thanks for the answered, i guess i won't be able to put the images to my packages until the day that they be in the Debian repositories..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about the screenshots provided by http://screenshots.debian.net. As can be seen in their about page:

> This is a public repository of screenshots taken from applications contained in the Debian GNU/Linux distribution and its derivates like Ubuntu. It was created to help getting an impression of what a certain software will look like on your desktop before you install it. **Everybody can take screenshots and upload them.**

So, it only takes a single revision of one of the administrators and you are up. Unless you use transitional packages, header files or debug packages, you can add screenshots for any package.

Comment: As i was telling to @derobert that screenshots data base it is only for the packages at the Debian/Ubuntu repository so i can not upload pictures for my packages (so actually there is no way of doing this, well, I'll give a try contacting the sys admin of the site). By the way, thanks for the edit. It seems that my English is not clear enough